# Maintain connection order on FIRRTL using Cat operator

Tags: chisel, register-transfer-level

I want to ask for any idea for the following problem :
I want to connect the input port of a block named *dut* whose width is 787:0 bits, to a byte interface. I am doing like following :

```
val io = this.IO(new VerilatorHarnessIO(input_byte_count, output_byte_count*2))
val dut = Module(new DUT(dut_conf))

// inputs
val input_bytes = Cat(io.input_bytes)
val input_width = input_byte_count * 8
dut.io.inputs := input_bytes(input_width-1, input_width - dut_conf.inputBits)
```

I want that the order of the connection is preserved, ie:

*Byte_0[7:0] ->input[7:0]*

*Byte_1[7:0] ->input[15:8]*

But what I am getting is :

*Byte_0[7:0] ->input[787:780]*

*Byte_1[7:0] ->input[779:772]*

It will be much easier to debug if the ports are matched.

Is there a way to make this connection in the right order?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `reverse` method before you `Cat` should do what you want.

Consider the following Chisel:

```scala
import chisel3._
import chisel3.stage.{ChiselStage, ChiselGeneratorAnnotation}
import chisel3.util.Cat

class Foo extends RawModule {
  val in = IO(Input(Vec(4, UInt(8.W))))
  val out = IO(Output(UInt(32.W)))

  out := Cat(in.reverse)
}

(new ChiselStage)
  .execute(Array.empty, Seq(ChiselGeneratorAnnotation(() => new Foo)))
```

This produces the following Verilog with the bytes in the order you're looking for:

```
module Foo(
  input  [7:0]  in_0,
  input  [7:0]  in_1,
  input  [7:0]  in_2,
  input  [7:0]  in_3,
  output [31:0] out
);
  wire [15:0] _T; // @[Cat.scala 29:58]
  wire [15:0] _T_1; // @[Cat.scala 29:58]
  assign _T = {in_1,in_0}; // @[Cat.scala 29:58]
  assign _T_1 = {in_3,in_2}; // @[Cat.scala 29:58]
  assign out = {_T_1,_T}; // @[<pastie> 25:7]
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

`Cat` appears backwards because it matches Verilog semantics and is thus backwards from the perspective of Scala semantics.

Consider:

```scala
val xs = List(8, 9, 10)
println(xs(0)) // 8
```

The left-most element is the lowest order index in Scala. However, in Verilog, you get the opposite:

```
assign x = {4'hde, 4'had};
```

The left-most part of that concatenation is actually the high-order nibble in the result. Chisel `Cat` was made to match Verilog semantics which makes it somewhat counter-intuitive in Scala.

As Schuyler mentioned, you can always `reverse` your `Vec` or `Seq` argument to `Cat`. Alternatively, you can cast to a `UInt` which will use the more intuitive Scala order:

```scala
import chisel3._

class Foo extends RawModule {
  val in = IO(Input(Vec(4, UInt(8.W))))
  val out = IO(Output(UInt(32.W)))

  out := in.asUInt
}
```

`.asUInt` is defined on all Chisel `Data`, so you can use it to cast `Bundles` and other types to `UInt` as well. The only catch is that many methods defined on `Vec` return `Seq`, the Scala supertype of `Vec` which is not a chisel `Data`. This means you cannot do something like `myVec.map(_ === 0.U).asUInt`. You can always cast a `Seq[T <: Data]` (ie. a `Seq` containing Chisel `Data` elements) to a `Vec` via `VecInit(mySeq)`, so you could do `VecInit(myVec.map(_ === 0.U)).asUInt`